# Может ли генератор речи, встроенный в Android воспроизвести английские фонетические знаки, транскрипцию?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-text-to-speech, синтезатор-речи

Может ли генератор (синтезатор) речи, встроенный в Android прочитать и воспроизвести фонетические знаки, транскрипцию? Типа:

краткие: ʌ, ə, æ, i, e, o, u

долгие: ɑ:, ə:, i:, ɔ:, u:

дифтонги: ɑɪ, au, eɪ, əu, ɛə, ɪə, ɔɪ, uə

Как озвучить их в приложении Андроид Студии?

Comment: Записать, или найти записи, и проиграть.

Comment: Проиграть (символы в речь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока на дату 21.04.18 - генератор не может!

Проверено!